# Change color of image on partial areas with out using Html5 canvas

Tags: html, css

Can we change color of image on partial areas(eg: change the hand color of a person in an image to red) with out using Html5 canvas

Comment: I want to konw that how it is done. they are customizing the image with out using sepperate images. They use image map. But how is it done http://shop.reebok.com/us/content/custom-mens-shoes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take an image.And with help of photoshop make another image with red hand(By putting color in that area).

And Do something like

HTML :

```
<div id="Library"></div>
```

CSS :

```
#Library {
background-image: url('http://www.hdwallpapers3d.com/wp-content/uploads/priyanka-chopra-image.jpg');
height: 70px;
width: 120px;
}

#Library:hover {
background-image: url('http://www.bubblews.com/assets/images/news/101694940_1380487096.jpg');
}
```

You can set height and width whatever you want.

Link of jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BjAQD/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can but you can fake it assuming it's one color you want to do it for. What you would do is take your image and make all of the parts you want to change color (let's say it's initially red) and turn it transparent (this means you're probably going to need to use a png).
Then you set a background color to the image and just alternate the color whenever you feel like it. The css and JS would look something like this (using jquery)

```
#weird-image { background-color: #FF0000; }
```

and

```
$("#weird-image").mouseover(function () {
    $this.css("background-color","#FFFF00");
}
```

Comment: can we turn an image to completly red or some thing else?